# Using Geometric Network toolbar?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, geometric-network

I've been using the Geometric Network tools for quite sometime now to trace electric distribution networks for my job and all of a sudden when try to trace the circuits and connected features from each particular transformer the trace won't work and the features aren't selecting. I have it set to Find Connected and the box in the Analysis dropdown and options is set to Selected Features. I can't figure out what has gone wrong. Also there hasn't been any ArcMap update since I'm still using 10.3.1.

Can anyone suggest a fix or know what's wrong?

Comment: Is this out-of-the box tracing, or some non-esri tool?

Comment: This is an ESRI tool, Utility Network Analyst. It's on the toolbar options. You drop a flag on the edge of a line feature and it will trace all connected features on that circuit. I use it all the time to confirm all equipment and conductors along primary and secondary electrical circuits are connected and now it's not tracing when using the Find Connected option.